# MySQL and PHPMyAdmin error (XAMPP)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

This is my first time setting this up. I'm running a Apache server and I'm trying to set my PHPMyAdmin and MySQL stuff. The only thing I changed in the PHPMyAdmin config file was

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = '(user)';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '(pass)';
```

And for the MySQL config file, I only changed

```
password       = (same pass as the other)
```

There's no # on it either. I'm getting an error "phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server." I checked them and they seemed fine, but I wouldn't know. Was I suppose to the the controluser default?

Comment: Try to connect to mysql server from command prompt using the command `mysql -u (user) -p` to check if your server running

Comment: @miltos - I'm using xampp and my control panel says it is. If it helps, I'm on Win 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

In phpMyAdmin, the controluser and controlpassword are used for [advanced features](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_controlpass), not to control log in. Since you didn't change the auth_type, the default of `cookie` prompts you for the username and password when you connect to phpMyAdmin; you don't need to hard code them to the configuration file.

Are you trying to connect as the root user? MySQL defaults to username root with a blank password. Not sure if XAMPP changes that off hand, but if so it should have prompted you for a password when you installed. If you forgot or don't know the root password, the MySQL manual [explains how to reset it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html).

Also, you don't hard code the password to the MySQL configuration file; user names and passwords are stored in the MySQL database itself. Storing the password in my.cnf will use that password when connecting from client programs, but isn't needed.